# Nessus HTML5 version 5.0.3 - PCI Scan

Tags: nessus

I've been searching for a couple days (and even contacted their support) to find out if Nessus (company is Tenable) has a bundle that scans for PCI compliance. The one that they gave me is the same as the rest of the defaults. It selects all 44 categories.

Because this is the HTML5 version there seems to be very little documentation/resources online.

Does anyone know the minimal requirements? I've done a filter search for any plugin that has the name "PCI" and this takes it down to a handful but i'm not sure if this excludes a ton of things either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would highly recommend checking out our sister site for Information Security professionals [security.se].

Comment: I would have migrated this to [security.se], but as mentioned in the answer there's a built-in option for PCI-DSS already.

Comment: @ChrisS: That's one of the things you have to do, yes.

Comment: What's the exact problem you're facing? It seems like you're looking for a PCI scan, but you've already found it...

Answer (score 2):

Nessus 5 has a scan policy, specifically designed for PCI-DSS audits. When performing a new scan, from the Scan policy section select "Prepare for PCI-DSS audits"

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the help guys! I was unaware of that website so I will be checking it out for sure. 
Cryc0s. The issue i'm having is that it is uploaded correctly to the nessus server. It is however selecting everything vs going through and disabling what is not needed for PCI. I will be running full scans ect later, but i didnt want them to be in this report.